# How can I create menu behavior using unnested markup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some output html that needs to be styled as a menu.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a>All</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>
      <span class="level0">Clothing</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>
      <span class="level1 parent_0">Shirts</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>
      <span class="level2 parent_0">Tee</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>
      <span class="level2 parent_0">Polo</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>
      <span class="level2 parent_0">Jersey</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>
      <span class="level2 parent_0">Dress</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>
      <span class="level1 parent_0">Hats</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>
      <span class="level2 parent_1">Beanie</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>
      <span class="level2 parent_1">Flexfit</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>
      <span class="level2 parent_1">Snapback</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>
      <span class="level2 parent_1">Strapback</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>
      <span class="level2 parent_1">Visor</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>
      <span class="level0">Accessories</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>
      <span class="level1 parent_2">Swag</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>
      <span class="level2 parent_2">Drink Cozy</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I can't change the markup except to add classes(or ids) to the spans based on a query which I have done. Now each span has the necessary information to target elements based on relationships but I can't target the elements using pseudo selectors like :hover to show or hide elements because of the "cascading" principle of css. That puts me in less familiar territory which is to use js or jQuery.

I've created the following fiddle with css classes applied. If you scroll to the bottom of the css you will see the selectors I've created to toggle the visibility of the targeted elements. The examples that I'm finding aren't very relevant to this case.

[The Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9pvbgy1j/)

How can I toggle the visibility of this html list's children based on their parent's hover state using only classes/ids?

Comment: Did you try to write some code to handle this?

Comment: @Dekel I will be glad to try when I have an understanding of what particularly I should be looking at in js. Although I'm in the process of discovering what that is, I thought it would be advantageous to post a question here while doing so.

Comment: Im confused, you want something to change based on if the parent is being hovered?

Comment: Do you want the sub menu's to only appear when you hover, or do you just want to change their colors on hover?

Comment: @WillDiFruscio I want the sub menus to appear when the parent is hovered over.

Comment: This is possible, one sec.

Comment: You deleted your css!! aghhh

Comment: @WillDiFruscio it's there when I pull it up. https://jsfiddle.net/9pvbgy1j/

Comment: When you say that you can't change the markup you mean the original source or you don't want to change it even using jquery?

Comment: I mean the original source, I'm not sure how changing it with jquery will affect things but I'm willing to see. The menu is auto generated for use with Isotope.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, with the requirements being you cannot change the HTML hierarchy.. I believe I have come up with a solution for you. Although it is ugly as sin, it does work. Basically the way it works is if you hover inside a level 2 element, it will find the next level 3 elements until it hits a different level 2 element. Then it will add a `.hovered` class to those elements. This is not a perfect solution, but I think it actually works quite well. You can add more mouseout events to polish it, but this will get you started. 
https://jsfiddle.net/9pvbgy1j/5/

```js
$('li.first').hover(function(){
 $(this).siblings('li.second').addClass('hovered');
}, function(e){
 if(!$(e.relatedTarget).is('span.level0')) {
  $(this).siblings('li.second').removeClass('hovered');
 }
})

$('li.second').hover(function(){
 $('li.third').removeClass('hovered');
 $(this).nextUntil('li.second','li.third').addClass('hovered');
}, function(e){
 if(!$(e.relatedTarget).is('span.level1')) {
  $(this).siblings('li.third').removeClass('hovered');
 }
})

$('li.third').hover(function(){
 $('li.fourth').removeClass('hovered');
 $(this).nextUntil('li.third').addClass('hovered');
}, function(e){
 if(!$(e.relatedTarget).is('span.level2')) {
  $(this).siblings('li.fourth').removeClass('hovered');
 }
})
```

```css
.isotope-options {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 500px;
}

.isotope-options a,
.isotope-options a:link,
.isotope-options a:visited,
.isotope-options a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.isotope-options {
 margin: auto;
 padding: 10px;
 text-align: center;
}
.isotope-options li {
 display: inline;
}
.isotope-options li.first{
 background: #1E90FF;
 border-radius: 5px;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 5px 10px;
 -moz-transition: background-color .3s;
 -o-transition: background-color .3s;
 -webkit-transition: background-color .3s;
 transition: background-color .3s;
 margin: 0;
}
.isotope-options span {
 font-size: 15px;
 font-style: unset;
 background: #1E90FF;
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding: 5px 10px;
 -moz-transition: background-color .3s;
 -o-transition: background-color .3s;
 -webkit-transition: background-color .3s;
 transition: background-color .3s;
}
.isotope-options .level1 {
 background: #657E97;
 width: 75%;
 margin:auto;
}
.isotope-options .level2 {
 background: #1B3855;
 width: 25%;
 margin:auto;
}

.isotope-options span:hover {
  background: #ADD8E6;
  color: #555;
}

/* Visibility Toggle Classes */

.level0 {
 display: block;
}
.level1.parent_0 {
 display: block;
}
.level2.parent_0 {
 display: block;
}
.level2.parent_1 {
 display: block;
}
.level1.parent_2 {
 display: block;
}
.level2.parent_2 {
 display: block;
}


li.second {
  display: block;
    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li.third {
  display: block;
    height: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
}

li.fourth {
  display: block;
    height: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
}

li.hovered {
  height: 1.75em;
}

li{
  transition: height .5s ease;
  transition-delay: .2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <ul class="isotope-options clearfix" data-filter-group="unnamed_filter">
      <li class="first"><a href="#filter" class="filterbutton" data-filter="">All</a></li>
      <li class="second">
        <a href="#filter" class="filterbutton" data-filter=".clothing">
          <span class="level0">Clothing</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="third">
        <a href="#filter" class="filterbutton" data-filter=".shirts">
          <span class="level1 parent_0">Shirts</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="fourth">
        <a href="#filter" class="filterbutton" data-filter=".tee">
          <span class="level2 parent_0">Tee</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="fourth">
        <a href="#filter" class="filterbutton" data-filter=".polo">
          <span class="level2 parent_0">Polo</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="fourth">
        <a href="#filter" class="filterbutton" data-filter=".jersey">
          <span class="level2 parent_0">Jersey</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="fourth">
        <a href="#filter" class="filterbutton" data-filter=".dress">
          <span class="level2 parent_0">Dress</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="third">
        <a href="#filter" class="filterbutton" data-filter=".hats">
          <span class="level1 parent_0">Hats</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="fourth">
        <a href="#filter" class="filterbutton" data-filter=".visor">
          <span class="level2 parent_1">Beanie</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="fourth">
        <a href="#filter" class="filterbutton" data-filter=".strapback">
          <span class="level2 parent_1">Flexfit</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="fourth">
        <a href="#filter" class="filterbutton" data-filter=".snapback">
          <span class="level2 parent_1">Snapback</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="fourth">
        <a href="#filter" class="filterbutton" data-filter=".flexfit">
          <span class="level2 parent_1">Strapback</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="fourth">
        <a href="#filter" class="filterbutton" data-filter=".beanie">
          <span class="level2 parent_1">Visor</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="second">
        <a href="#filter" class="filterbutton" data-filter=".clothing">
          <span class="level0">Clothing</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="third">
        <a href="#filter" class="filterbutton" data-filter=".shirts">
          <span class="level1 parent_0">Shirts</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="fourth">
        <a href="#filter" class="filterbutton" data-filter=".tee">
          <span class="level2 parent_0">Tee</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="fourth">
        <a href="#filter" class="filterbutton" data-filter=".polo">
          <span class="level2 parent_0">Polo</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="fourth">
        <a href="#filter" class="filterbutton" data-filter=".jersey">
          <span class="level2 parent_0">Jersey</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="fourth">
        <a href="#filter" class="filterbutton" data-filter=".dress">
          <span class="level2 parent_0">Dress</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="third">
        <a href="#filter" class="filterbutton" data-filter=".hats">
          <span class="level1 parent_0">Hats</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="fourth">
        <a href="#filter" class="filterbutton" data-filter=".visor">
          <span class="level2 parent_1">Beanie</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="fourth">
        <a href="#filter" class="filterbutton" data-filter=".strapback">
          <span class="level2 parent_1">Flexfit</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="fourth">
        <a href="#filter" class="filterbutton" data-filter=".snapback">
          <span class="level2 parent_1">Snapback</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="fourth">
        <a href="#filter" class="filterbutton" data-filter=".flexfit">
          <span class="level2 parent_1">Strapback</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="fourth">
        <a href="#filter" class="filterbutton" data-filter=".beanie">
          <span class="level2 parent_1">Visor</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Pat but as stated in the post I can not change the html markup to nest it as you have.

Comment: Just edited my post with a new solution, one that doesn't involve changing the html around. Try it now.

Comment: This is great, the menu is showing clothing twice instead of clothing and accessories but it is what I am trying to achieve. I'm marking this as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I just copied and pasted clothing twice for a proof of concept -- should of added accessories back in before posting.

Comment: I caught that, no worries... hope your generosity is returned to you.

Comment: I was hasty when I accepted this answer. Markup was added to the html in the form of li classes. I didn't realize it until I started to add it to my page. I can't add those classes so I need to target the child span in an unclassified sibling. I've been trying but no luck so far.